# Multi Query Attention implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

Im trying to implement the multi query attention as found in Google's PaLM model. However, im not sure if my implementation is correct. If it is, is there a better way to implement this. I can't seem to find any open implementation of it anywhere. Im using PyTorch 2.0.

```
class CausalAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_embd, n_head, dropout):
        super(CausalAttention, self).__init__()
        assert n_embd % n_head == 0

        self.q_attn = nn.Linear(n_embd, n_embd, bias=False)
        self.k_attn = nn.Linear(n_embd, n_embd // n_head, bias=False)
        self.v_attn = nn.Linear(n_embd, n_embd // n_head, bias=False)

        self.c_proj = nn.Linear(n_embd, n_embd, bias=False)

        self.attn_dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.resid_dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

        self.n_head = n_head
        self.n_embd = n_embd
        self.dropout = dropout

    def forward(self, x):
        B, T, C = x.shape

        q = self.q_attn(x)
        q = q.view(B, T, self.n_head, C // self.n_head).transpose(1, 2)

        k = self.k_attn(x)
        k = k.view(B, T, 1, C // self.n_head).transpose(1, 2)

        v = self.v_attn(x)
        v = v.view(B, T, 1, C // self.n_head).transpose(1, 2)

        y = F.scaled_dot_product_attention(
            q,
            k,
            v,
            attn_mask=None,
            dropout_p=self.dropout if self.training else 0,
            is_causal=True,
        )

        y = y.transpose(1, 2).contiguous().view(B, T, C)

        y = self.resid_dropout(self.c_proj(y))

        return y
```

The code runs fine, just not sure if the implementation is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop by my [repo](https://github.com/Andy-Dang12/How-Transformers-Work/blob/main/transformers/attention.py), I just implement it few day ago to understand how transformers work. In my opinion, It very easy to understand because it not be optimized. I just implement step by step.
Another implement you can find in here:

1. [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/mosaicml/mpt-7b-chat/blob/main/attention.py#L204)
2. [lucidrains](https://github.com/lucidrains/PaLM-pytorch/blob/main/palm_pytorch/palm_pytorch.py#L133)